# Button in simple ListView onClick

Tags: java, android, xml

So I have simple listview with a list item that contains a textview, and two imageviews.
I want both of the imageviews to act as buttons. Unfortunately, I can't even get one of them to work. The list view loads but then the app crashes when either image is touched. Here is the xml for the listitem:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="16dp">

    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_email"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/LightGrey" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/internet"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_web_site" />
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the layout with the listview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvDepartments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:listSelector="@color/Navy"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the related java code:

```
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.staff_layout);        
    staffmemberlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvDepartments);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>                                 (getApplicationContext(),R.layout.emailbrowsingcard,R.id.name, d);
    staffmemberlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    mailbutton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.email);
    mailbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "This line would appear on clicking this icon",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: Could we have a logcat as well, please?

Comment: There is also an `ImageButton` view for this. If you set its background to `android.R.color.transparent` then it will appear just like an `ImageView`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tod.android.bths/com.tod.android.bths.FinalStaff}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: switched to ImageButton... doesn't help my case

Comment: Best Way you have to create **custom adapter** (BaseAdapter).After you have to easily access any of the view which is inflated in listview.

Comment: creating custom adapter now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isnt going to work because the ImageView is in the item list so you should consider doing..

```
 mailButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.email);
```

where row is the item list. remember the ImageView isn't in staff_layout, it is in your item_layout.

to make it works you need to move this block:

```
mailbutton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.email);
mailbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "This line would appear on clicking this icon",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

to the getView() in your adapter class. and let the View get `findViewById` or have an instance of the item_layout view in order to reach the buttons.

Comment: how would i identify the row? is it the top linearlayout in the listitem??? So `row = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.<theid>)`

Comment: can you add the your Custom adapter class so you can understand it well and I can help you out.

Comment: wasn't using a custom adapter... building one now.. can figure it out from here.. thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

you should use a custom adapter for that and in custom adapter use findViewById for finding imageviews and setting listener

> this is a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html